# Data obfuscation in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

What is the best practice for Data Obfuscation in SQL Server?

We'd like to use masked Production data in our UAT system.

If we want to do it quickly, and with a higher level of obsfucation, what approach should be taken?  I'm thinking about Character scrambling for people's given name and family name, but how?  Should I create a function myself or there is any predefined functions available to use?  I don't want to spend time re-inventing the wheel :)

How about for date fields?  For example should date of birth be randomly picked from the whole table and assigned to a record, or there is a better way of doing that?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I wish I could upvote you 100 points just for thinking about this! I have seen this subject overlooked so many times it's untrue - so well done. From what I understand you actually want to scramble the data within the fields themselves, and although I understand what you are trying to achieve it might not be quite necessary to do so - although it should be considered on a case-by-case basis.

Most data protection laws revolve around the ability to correctly associate a piece of data with an individual - for example a date of birth or a phone number. You can meet the requirements of the law by ensuring that when you move your data out of production into UAT it is jumbled up so it is not easily re-mapped to the original person - especially when you jumble forename and surnames.

However, this does not address the issue for instance of let's say contact details. You can meet the requirements of the law by jumbling the data but the phone numbers are still real, the emails still real etc... they are just not assigned to the correct person. For this I recommend if at all possible clearing that data before passing it into UAT, Red Gate do a piece of software called [Data Generator](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-generator/) that can create random test data for you so that you can repopulate the fields with data that can be tested against.

As for data scrambling: there exists many applications that do this for you and honestly you are correct in not wanting to reinvent the wheel. The one that we use at our company is a product called [Data Masker](http://www.datamasker.com/index.html) by a company called Net2000. The license is pretty cheap, it works extremely fast and you don't have to worry about having to disable all your constraints before scrambling the database.

You can of course roll your own solution should you not find anything that meets your requirements - if you do decide to do this I would strongly recommend using CLR procedures to do it as it is much more flexible than pure TSQL (not to say that you can't use TSQL see [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=100066)).

Once you have chosen an application to perform this for you the next thing you need to decide is what is it you actually want/need to scramble? Honestly your best resource for this is your company legal team and or the company auditors. I know that sometimes we may not like working with them but they will be much nicer to you for approaching them and asking them the question rather than trying to do it on your own and get it wrong, there is absolutely nothing wrong with asking for help - especially when it is as important as this.

I hope this helps you and I wish you good luck in your quest... ;-)

Comment: If I could, I would give place an additional upvote for mentioning company policy.

Comment: The legal requirements are determined by stakeholders. I should implement it now.

Comment: Mr Bownstone your explanation is excellent as always. Thank you. I'm going to check CLR function for this and have an eye on T-SQL as well. See which one fits better and is faster to build.

Answer (score 12):

Mr. Brownstone hit the nail right on the head.  Now to help you out a bit, here is my "garble" function, used to obfuscate strings (funny results with names!).  Pass in a string, it returns a garbled string.  Include it in update statements against string columns.  Change the data length as you see fit.

```
---------------------
-- Garble Function --
---------------------
-- Make a function to slightly garble the strings
IF (object_id('fn_Garble') is not null)
  drop function fn_Garble
go
create function fn_Garble
(
  @String varchar(255)
)  
returns varchar(255)
as
BEGIN
  select @String = replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(@String,'o','e'),'a','o'),'i','a'),'u','i'),'t','p'),'c','k'),'d','th'),'ee','e'),'oo','or'),'ll','ski')
  return @String
END
go
```

Comment: Sounds familiar?  (Just an illustration of your point.)  a om o SQL Server thBo an eppowo konotho. a om phe presathenp ef Meprepelas threomwore onth kekang Waph SQL. We prevathe thopobose kensilponps pe voraeis piblak onth pravope sekper ergonazopaens.
a om o pekhnakol ethaper fer SQL Server Mogozane onth phe oipher ef phe p-SQL 101 seraes ef orpakles / e-bek.
a hove ben o SQL Server thBo sanke phe both elth thoys ef SQL 4.2.

Comment: heh...took me a while to recognize it.  There seems to be a lot of non-garbled words in there.  I only ever used it against first names, last names, city names.  Just a silly little function.  I would not stake my career on it.

Comment: I appreciate the approach - kept simple but working.  And a plus is that the text is still legible.  I couldn't understand it though :)

Answer (score 8):

I had to do this for my clients retail sales data. For names I went to the census and downloaded all the first and last names, ran them through a loop to join every first to every last, added sex code and loaded it into a table in all upper case. I then had a table with about 400 million unique names. I used upper case as our current data was not in upper case so  I could more easily tell data that was scrubbed.

When I scrubbed my user data I swapped out the names, for birthday I put everyone to Jan 1 of the year they were actually born and updated any phone numbers with their zip code (my data was US only). Email addresses became firs initial plus last name @mycompany.co. The postal address gave me the most grief but I kept the city, state and zip because I believe them to not be an issue if the address is changed. I had a co-worker who had some program that generated garbled letters and updated the address line with that.

Anywhere I had duplicated data but still had a FK to the main user (bad design yes, but not mine) I updated that data too so the name was consistent across the database for user x.

Overall my data was still very readable although address did not make any sense. It took me a couple of days to get all this working but once it was done and a sql agent job was created I could scrub the data in as little as 15 minutes.

Comment: I like your approach. Regarding given name and surname, I think if the data set is big enough, with a good level of variation, we can use it as the source, rather than having to download names from census website. Querying the data by SELECT DISTICT will tell us home many unique values we have to play with.

Answer (score 0):

For obfuscating a single field, how about using the HASHBYTES function (in SQL 2008+)? You can choose your algorithm (MD5 is probably enough) provided you salt your data. So instead of just
`SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', <LAST NAME FIELD>)`
make sure you do `SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', <LAST NAME FIELD> + '<my salt string>')` and now you have a hash that can't be easily brute forced.

It's an actual function that is supportable, repeatable, and probably a lot quicker. Depending on how much you need to truly secure vs just obfuscate, you could also use a weaker, quicker hash.

Comment: You shouldn't be using MD5 in this day & age, it's inherantly insecure.

Comment: OK...here are your choices with HASHBYTES:
`MD2 | MD4 | MD5 | SHA | SHA1 | SHA2_256 | SHA2_512`

Something for everyone!! (including, yes, ones you shouldn't use). So say we are using SHA2_512...anything else problematic with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at dbatools PowerShell module for a free option for Static Data Masking, written by Chrissy Lemaire (@chrissy-lemaire) and her team. All of their tools are great, so I'm sure this is worth a look.

The two commands to look up in dbatools are:
New-DbaDbMaskingConfig
Invoke-DbaDbDataMasking

Take a look at the blog post announcing this: [automated data masking](https://dbatools.io/mask/)

Comment: Link only answers aren't very helpful. You could improve your answer by giving examples of how to use the cmdlets, etc.